# Do I need to unbind all event listeners on my React components in componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, event-listener

I am working a React app where I have few components in different routes. I am using the `onClick={this.handleClick}` pattern to bind events

```
<>
<ParentComp>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
</ParentComp>
</>
```

Now, my question is, do I need to worry about removing the handler from the above button when I navigate to another route or even simply when the component is getting unmounted ffor some reason? And if yes how do I do that in the `componentWillUnmount` method since I will not have a reference to this button?

**Edit**
The event handler is not calling anykind of setTimeout or setInterval or anything of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

No. With syntax react will take care of add and removing the listener when needed. You should worry about removing the handler when you `addEventListener` by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No, React takes care of the event handling. Also note that React DOM takes care of handling DOM rendering. Your `<button />` JSX will not create a button element each time that the component is rendered. It defines a `button` node in the React Virtual tree that then is sync with the real DOM.

Because of this React doesn't set event handlers directly in the node, for example if you inspect the `<button>` element with the debugger you'll not see an `onClick` listener attached to it! What's going on? This article explains it: https://medium.com/the-guild/getting-to-know-react-doms-event-handling-system-inside-out-378c44d2a5d0

TL;DR: React uses a global event handler at the root of your page, then it takes care of dispatching the event, so even if you get the `button` ref and then you use `removeEventListener` it will not have any effect.

You only need to worry about cleaning event listeners if you use another non-React library that uses the DOM directly. But also in that case, the browser will garbage collect the listeners when the node is removed from the DOM.